# Hide the ViewController till the webView is loaded (till the delegate method is called)

Tags: ios, delegates

I have a UIWebView as a subview in ViewController i present modally, I want to present the view controller only after the WebView is loaded.

How should i approach this? I was thinking about delegation/block callback but then the viewController wont be even called,
I'm looking for a way to hide the ViewController till the delegate method "webViewDidFinishLoad" is called

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Container View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) to contain ViewController B. It will be called when entering ViewController A. When `webViewDidFinishLoad` in ViewController B is triggered you can set `containerView.alpha = 1;`